# UITableView Won't Display Data

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView and it refuses to show any data, Xcode isn't showing any errors or warnings. Not sure why this is because the same code was working in a different app (obviously the names of array and tableview were different). I have the delegate and datasource both set as the view view-controller. If there is anything i missed please tell me!
Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface UIViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize CafeTableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self performSelector:@selector(RetriveData)];
    [CafeTableView reloadData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)RetriveData {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"CafeList"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",objects);
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d Cafes.", objects.count);
            cafeListArry = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];

        }else{
            UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                               message:(@"There has been an error loading the Cafe List Please Try Again!")
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [theAlert show];
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
    }];
    [CafeTableView reloadData];
}

//-------------------TABLE VIEW-----------------------

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return cafeListArry.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CafeCell";
    CafeListCell *cell = [CafeTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    PFObject *tempObject = [cafeListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"CafeName"];
    cell.detail.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"NumberOfStars"];

    return cell;
}


@end
```

Comment: Reload the table after you get the data, not before.

Comment: And fix your error checking. You want `if (objects)`, not `if (!error)`.

Comment: @rmaddy I am reloading the table after I get my data.

Comment: No, you're not reloading after you get the data. You need to have  reloadData inside the completion block. findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock is an asynchronous method, so your reloadData call happens before the data comes back, the way you have it now.

Comment: @rdelmar That crashes the app. I moved it up one line so before the  `}]; `

Comment: That's not inside the completion block. You should put it in the if clause right after you create the cafeListArray.

Comment: @rdelmar so in the if !(error)

Comment: Yes, except your if clause should be if(objects) as rmaddy suggested.

Comment: @rdelmar the app crashes if I do that `Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.`

Comment: You have other problems then, not related to your question. That warning shouldn't be causing a crash.

Comment: @rdelmar it didn't say that until I moved the reload data and this code worked as it is pre iOS 8.0 which is odd that it no longer works

Comment: It didn't say that before because it wasn't trying to create any cells before. 
The problem isn't in the code you posted anymore (After you moved the `reloadData` call). It might be in `CafeListCell`. Paste its code here, along with the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: P.S. @user3784444, the "error" that you posted a few comments above is a warning not an error... In the comment below Cihan's answer though you included the error that followed that warning. The *error* is: `Cafe[56352:176049] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7dc58610 2015-02-15 21:06:20.789 Cafe[56352:176049] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7dc58610'` and Cihan added the explanation of what might be causing the error to his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your call to `reloadData` inside the block as others have suggested and change the if condition as follows:

```
- (void)RetriveData {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"CafeList"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@",objects);
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d Cafes.", objects.count);
            cafeListArry = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            [CafeTableView reloadData];  // HERE
        }else{
            UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                               message:(@"There has been an error loading the Cafe List Please Try Again!")
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [theAlert show];
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Also, as suggested by Lyndsey in the comments, change the following line

```
cell.detail.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"NumberOfStars"];
```

to

```
cell.detail.text = [[tempObject objectForKey:@"NumberOfStars"] stringValue];
```

because you said that it's a number, not a string.

Comment: Crashes how? Does this block get executed in a separate thread?

Comment: It says this `Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
2015-02-15 21:06:20.784 Cafe[56352:176049] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7dc58610
2015-02-15 21:06:20.789 Cafe[56352:176049] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7dc58610'`

Comment: The code is the same as the default code for UItableview cells class with 2 outlets title and detail

Comment: @user3784444 Is `[tempObject objectForKey:@"NumberOfStars"]` an NSNumber?

Comment: Yes it column is listed as a number on the database

Comment: @user3784444 Then change this line: `cell.detail.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"NumberOfStars"];` to this: `cell.detail.text = [[tempObject objectForKey:@"NumberOfStars"] stringValue];`

Comment: It works now however the numberofstars isn't being displayed. Perhaps the number needs to be converted to a string?

Comment: There is nothing else wrong with the code.  Is the label positioned correctly and actually visible? Check that by setting its text to a dummy value.

Comment: @CihanTek i did cell.detail.text = @"5"; and it's not visible.

Comment: @CihanTek never mind the tableview is cut off not sure how ill fix it but what you told me to do worked! Thanks a Bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the delegates are connected in xib file or not if not then please connect properly and please call the [tableview reloadData]; method at the time when you want bind the data with table